# Javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, createelement

I am currently learning Javascript DOM and innerHTML and found some problems in understanding innerHTML.

Here are my codes: http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/bfjx1w70/1/

I have learnt standard DOM method and innerHTML methods and it works fine, BUT I don't know why it is wrong to code the following:

```
// this method fails
var element2 = document.createElement('p'); 
element2.innerHTML = "hello <em>Herbert</em>";

// standard methods of innerHTML method I learnt from textbook, BUT it requires to type tags in HTML
var element3 = document.getElementById('el');
element3.innerHTML = "innerHTML: hello <em>Herbert</em>";
```

I want to ask why it does not work for the first method. What is the problem of doing in this way? In addition, what if I don't want to type anything (including tags) in HTML and want to use innerText to fulfil the same output as what the JSFiddle shows "hello *Herbert*"?

Comment: sorry for wrong typo... it should be innerHTML...
and I have no idea why the first method is wrong...

Comment: I cannot see any difference now that the first code won't work.

Comment: amazing second code work without appending (your edit is ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is the `innerText` usage. For most purposes, I would stay away from that in general, as `innerHTML` works for both situations. (text and markup)

Although I suppose `innerText` has it's charms if you want to display HTML code as it is rather than render it.

So, because you have an HTML tag inside the string, it's not a normal text node. If you simply used 'hello Herbert' instead of 'hello *Herbert*' it would work.

```js
var element2 = document.getElementById('el'); 

element2.innerText = "hello Herbert";
```

```html
<p id='el'></p>
```

The other problem is though you have the element, until you have actually put it in the DOM, it is useless, which is why example 2 isn't working.

Try

```
document.body.appendChild(element2);
```

So,

```js
var element2 = document.createElement('p'); 

element2.innerHTML = "hello <em>Herbert</em>";

document.body.appendChild(element2);
```

Hope it helps! Look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp for more info.

Comment: Hey, if you're going to downvote my answer can you tell me why?

Comment: OP ask if innerText doesn't work but innerHTML work. why?

Comment: Good point. I actually didn't notice that. I've edited it it to encompass that.

Comment: @Tobsta: You might consider rollback. The OP has edited out his use of innerText.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"hello <em>Herbert</em>"` contains html tag (em) so `innerText` won't work but `innerHTML` work.

Comment: sorry for the typo... I mistype the code as innerText, it should be innerHTML...
and the code does not work too

Comment: did you append the html?

Answer (score 0):

The text `"hello <em>Herbert</em>"` is not exactly a text, as it has HTML Content in it. You really need to use `innerHTML` for this case:

```
element2.innerHTML = "hello <em>Herbert</em>";
```

Comment: sorry for the typo... I mistype the code as innerText, it should be innerHTML... and the code does not work too

Answer (score 0):

With `innerText` you can only apply plain Strings without formatting to an element. Useful in a dynamic function if you don't want that the text inside an element gets formatted. If it contains tags, they will be just shown as plain text. With `innerHTML` you can add anything to that element, including HTML-Tags.

EDIT: Now I've just seen that your problem was that the element wasn't even displaying at all, I just thought you wonder why Herbert didn't got italic. In this case it's because you didn't append the 2nd element to the body, like you did in the first version. The third version isn't creating an element, it uses an existing one, therefore you don't need to append it. ;)